# Can someone assist me in creating the following animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Basically, want something like so

```
TEXT_____________________[img]


'TEXT' is actual label for example `<div>LABEL</div>`

'_____________' is a `hr` element

'[img]' is a small image, for example a magnifying glass
```

The desired animation is that when user clicks on [img] a search input box slows appears to the left of image, for example after click:

```
TEXT________ [search-box] [img]
```

The [img] should be in same spot floated right, the only thing changes is that the `hr` gets shrunk although the whole element should be same width.

I have some prototype but its a little hacky and ugly, can someone suggest a nice solution?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/BTFEd/2/

Yea something like that fiddle, but the image icon stays at the far right and the hr just shrinks or expands depending on the visibility of the searchbox.

Comment: Posting your prototype will probably get us a kick start instead of making everything from the ground. Some of the markup/css in a fiddle/bin would be nice too.

Comment: Can we see a Fiddle of what you have? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté hey added fiddle

Comment: @Mooseman hey added fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but hide the `hr` before:

```
$("#s-box").hide();
$("#search-icon").click( function(){
    $("#s-box").animate({ width: 'toggle'});
    $(".my-hr").animate({ width: 'toggle'});
});
```